# How can I print the first three rows and the last three rows one under another in ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

In ORACLE SQL, I want to print the first two and the last two rows one under the other. How can I do this with a one query? Suppose you have table with ten rows. I want to print the first two rows and the last two rows as below:

| Row Number | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 9 | C |
| 10 | D |

Comment: First three rows of *what*?  Remember that tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  There is no such thing as the first three rows of a table.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: What is *print*? [`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS67324) or just SQL result set?

Comment: Just SQL result set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **row_number()over(order by row_number)** window function to achieve what you are looking for. Even you can have first two rows order by row_number and last two rows order by column valuess  if you want (row_number()over(order by row_number)FirstRowNumber, row_number()over(order by valuess desc)LastRowNumber )).

**Table structure and insert statement:**

```
create table tableName (Row_Number int, Valuess varchar(20));
insert into tablename values(1,'A');
insert into tablename values(2,'B');
insert into tablename values(9,'C');
insert into tablename values(10,'D');
insert into tablename values(11,'E');
insert into tablename values(12,'F');
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER,Valuess FROM (
select ROW_NUMBER,Valuess,row_number()over(order by row_number)FirstRowNumber, row_number()over(order by row_number desc)LastRowNumber from tablename ) T
WHERE FIRSTROWNUMBER<=2 OR LASTROWNUMBER<=2
ORDER BY FIRSTROWNUMBER
```

**Output:**

| ROW_NUMBER | VALUESS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 11 | E |
| 12 | F |

Answer (score 0):

I think you need below query,

```
select t.*
from (select table1.*, row_number() over (order by [Row Number]) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from table1
     ) t
where seqnum in( 1,2) or seqnum in( cnt, cnt-1);
```

Comment: What is t.* and table1.* ?

Comment: **table1** is your database table name .  And **t** is my subquery allies name. And * means, selecting all column of the table.